# E/flash_archive: [ERROR][unzip_archive_in_extract_dir] unzip failed: /sdcard/Download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

Tags: android, virtual-machine, genymotion

My app can not run on Genymotion virtual machine,and I'm trying to flash the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip  to my virtual machine. But just when i drag the file to the virtual machine and click ok,unknow error occured and the logfile shows below:

> E/flash_archive: [ERROR][unzip_archive_in_extract_dir] unzip failed:
>   /sdcard/Download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

CAN ANY BODY HELP ME OUT,THINKS ANY WAY!

Answer (score 2):

I was getting same error when trying to flash a zip file placed at C:\Users\nkumawat\Desktop\Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip with adb shell

```
adb shell flash-archive.sh C:\Users\nkumawat\Desktop\Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip
```

Or with DRAG-DROP method.

Result was:

```
*uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats)

C:UsersnkumawatDesktopGenymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip seems to be a zip archive

[flash_archive] Creating tmp dir

rm: /data/local/tmp/sanitized.zip: No such file or directory

[flash_archive] Unzip archive

unzip: can't open C:UsersnkumawatDesktopGenymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip[.zip]

[ERROR][unzip_archive_in_extract_dir] unzip failed: C:UsersnkumawatDesktopGenymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

{Result:KO};*
```

Got solution like this :

1. Push your zip file to /sdcard/download
2. Now flash zip file

   ```
    adb push C:\Users\nkumawat\Desktop\Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip /sdcard/download
   ```

```
    adb shell flash-archive.sh /sdcard/download/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip
```

Now reboot adb

```
adb reboot
```

Hope this will work,Worked for mine.